# Display block and height not working for image

Tags: html, css

So I want my image to be automatically resized when screen resolution is under 740 pixels.
This code is outside @media.

```css
header img {
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
  header img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/137694/isolated/lists/35e10823069d1767521320dc34475465-triangle-logo-geometric.png">
</header>
```

This code is not working! Why? When I check the code in chrom dev tools, these properties are deleted out except `width:100%;`!

Comment: I converted your code into a live demo and can't reproduce the problem. (The code you included in the question was missing the `}` at the end but I assume that  was a transcription error. If it wasn't, then your problem was caused by a typo.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The first definition is the default style. Add !important to enforce the screen style

```
@media screen and (max-width: 740px){
   header img{
       height:auto !important;
   }
```

Comment: The selectors have equal specificity and are applied in order. Adding `!important` should have no effect on this at all.

Comment: Worked out for me.

Comment: @TomsEglite — Most likely: (1) You hit a cached version of the CSS when you tested (2) You changed the CSS in your text editor and didn't properly save the changes before testing them. (3) The code in the question is not a true representation of the code causing the problem. Adding `!important` doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css